# How to detect estimote beacon when app is killed in ios?

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4, beacon, estimote

i am new in **estimote** beacon programming .i want to detect the **estimote** beacon when app is closed. And when beacon is detected then fire the particular notification. how i can done it?
give me suggestions please. i had done the following code. but i can not getting any notification

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
 beaconManager.delegate = self
        beaconManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
        beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)
}

func beaconManager(_ manager: Any, didEnter region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        NSLog("beaconManager : didEnter Called")
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Beacon Detected"
        content.body = "Enter region"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

        let trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region:region, repeats:false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Enter region", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
func beaconManager(_ manager: Any, didExitRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
            NSLog("beaconManager : didExitRegion Called")
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = "Beacon Detected"
            content.body = "Exit region"
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

            let trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region:region, repeats:false)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Enter region", content: content, trigger: trigger)
            center.add(request) { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In app delegate write the desired code under estimate delegate methods. Sample code as follows,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
if launchOptions["UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey"] != nil {
    beaconManager = ESTBeaconManager()
    beaconManager.delegate = self
    // don't forget the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in your Info.plist
    beaconManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    beaconManager.startMonitoring(for: ESTBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID, identifier: "AppRegion"))
    }
    return true
}

func beaconManager(_ manager: ESTBeaconManager, didEnter region: ESTBeaconRegion) {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "Enter region"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName as? String
    UIApplication.shared.presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
}
func beaconManager(_ manager: ESTBeaconManager, didExitRegion region: ESTBeaconRegion) {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "Exit region"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName as? String
    UIApplication.shared.presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
}
```

This is old code, may have few changes. Follow estimate community's thread for more information. You can find your problem on this thread https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/203253193-Pushing-notifications-from-iBeacon-when-the-app-is-in-the-background-or-killed

Comment: Put the code in your question with format please. Difficult to read them in comments.

Comment: does this code triggers notifications when app is in foreground and beacon is within range?

Comment: just fired one time when exit and app in foreground. but does not work when app is killed

Comment: while entering also it is working then, l'll surf around and let you know if I have any idea.